# Does fs in JavaScript has the ability to edit files in GitHub repo through Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, fs

I'm trying to make a Discord bot. I am wondering if I use fs and create a file does that file translate over to GitHub if that is what I am using to deploy?

I've explained a little bit more in the comments section.

Comment: It depends. Are you committing that file? Are you pushing it to the repository? Does that file become part of your application once created? Is this something you're going to do when deployed or just during development?

Comment: No, I'm creating that file while my bot is running. Basically I want to store the settings for each discord server and I'm wondering if my bot creates or edits a json file does it appear in github and how it will appear if it does. The reason is that I want the settings to remain the same and not reset every single time I run/deploy the bot on heroku. @tadman

Comment: You're describing a database. Use a database, or if that's impractical, use an object store like Amazon S3. Don't try and manage state with plain files. On Heroku the server is completely ephemeral, these files will get trashed. Putting a key with commit rights on that server is super dangerous.

Comment: Heroku has a number of database options to pick from, so you shouldn't be stuck for lack of those.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try to find a database that fits my needs then. @tadman

Comment: Does anyone have a recommendation for a database?